# Is it possible to automate constraint propagation with Rc in Rust

Tags: rust

[image]

Consider the above diagram representing a common constraint satisfaction problem:

- The hexagons are cells on a hexagonal grid extending in any of its 6 directions. For simplicity, I've included just 3 of these, `A`, `B`, and `C`.
- Each hexagon contains a set of `N` values commonly referred to as the hexagon's "domain". In this example, `domain = {red, blue}` and  `|domain| = N = 2`.
- A constraint is defined as an edge from one particular domain value of a hexagon to the domain value of another hexagon. So an example here would be `A_blue -> B_red`.

  - An edge will **not** appear interior to the hexagon. So `A_red -> A_blue` is not possible.
  - Cycles may be present. Either directly or indirectly (through another hexagon).
  - **Technically**, edges can appear across the grid (between non-neighbors) but that detail is irrelevant to this question.

Now, consider an operation where you'd remove a domain value from a hexagon. Doing this will affect other hexagon's domains, and cause domain values to be removed from other hexagons. For example, removing `blue` from `A` will cause `A_blue -> C_red -> B_blue -> A_red` all to be removed. However, it will **not** cause `C_blue` to be removed because `C_blue` has `2` edges pointing to it (the other from `B_red`).

---

The question is, how to propagate this "rippling" changing out. i.e. when one domain value is removed, how to propagate the change to all other hexagons. There's a ton of algorithms out there optimizing the efficiency of this operation, but I'm more interested in how to automatically propagate this change out in Rust (if it is possible). Allow me to explain.

Normally, you'd keep a counter for each domain value for every hexagon, when a domain value is removed, decrement this counter for neighboring (affected) hexagons. If this counter reach `0`, then you'd know it's time to *further* propagate the change, a fancy BFS/DFS if you will.

---

But I'm curious if using `std::rc::Rc` will allow me to **automatically** decrement this counter, since `std::rc::Rc` is a counter anyways.

So far, I've thought about combining `std::rc::Rc` with `std::rc::Weak`, where I'd store a `Weak` reference of other `std::rc::Rc` domain values inside the hexagon. Then I'd somehow drop the contents of this `Weak` reference so that the `Rc` stored inside gets dropped, and this change ripples out, but I don't think I'm heading in the right direction. I might need interior mutability. Or maybe this isn't possible at all.

Very new to Rust. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In you example, shouldn't `B_red` be dropped immediately? There are no edges pointing to it?

Comment: Also, the hard part to figure out is probably the value removal: if you use `Rc`s, you can't just arbitrarily drop a value to which other references exist. One possibility might be to have hexagons refer weakly to all values in them; and for each edge make a strong reference and a backwards weak reference. Then what you can do is: select the value to drop, find all values pointing to it using the backwards references, and delete those edges. This should ripple-drop the selected value and other values, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

Consider a simple example with two domain values connected by a single edge:

```
A -> B
```

`A` contains a `Weak` pointer to `B`, which represents the edge between them. We want the deletion of `A` to result in the deletion of `B`. However, when we upgrade `A`'s `Weak` pointer to an `Rc`, there are now *two* strong references to `B`. Dropping the newly acquired `Rc` only decrements the counter back to 1.

The cascading effect you describe only works if the `Rc`s are nested recursively, like in a linked list.

```rust
struct Node {
    next: Rc<Node>,
}
```

This works because you get a call stack like:

```
 - Node::drop()          // Head of list dropped, which contained...
  - Rc::<Node>::drop()   // the only Rc pointing to...
   - Node::drop()        // the second element, which contained...
    - Rc::<Node>::drop() // the only Rc pointing to...
     - Node::drop()      // the third element, which...
      - etc.
```

With an arbitrary graph structure, the nodes typically live in flat storage, like a `Vec<Rc<Node>>`. In this case, the `drop` implementation of one of the `Node`s would need to "reach up" the ownership hierarchy to remove another element of the `Vec`. This isn't possible without unsafe code and is very much an anti-pattern in Rust.

Note that some other languages (e.g. Java, C#) are able to achieve what you want because they have garbage collection, cycle detection, and most importantly *no concept of ownership*. In such languages, if you have a pointer to an object, you can modify it as if you owned it, and the details (like where it's stored and when it's destroyed) are taken care of behind the scenes.

---

In Rust, graphs are typically implemented using indices or IDs instead of pointers. A *very* simple directed graph might look like:

```rust
struct Node {
    num_incoming: usize,
    outgoing: Vec<usize>,
}

struct Graph {
    // Increment every time a node is added.
    next_id: usize,
    nodes: HashMap<usize, Node>,
}
```

Deleting a node then requires DFS/BFS as you mention, in this case BFS:

```
impl Graph {
    fn remove(&mut self, id: usize) {
        let removed = self.nodes.remove(&id).unwrap();
        
        // For simplicity, assume no incoming edges.
        assert_eq!(removed.num_incoming, 0);

        let mut queue = VecDeque::from_iter(removed.outgoing);

        while let Some(other) = queue.pop_front() {
            let Entry::Occupied(entry) = self.nodes.entry(other) else {
                panic!("missing node with id {id}");
            };

            // Decrement the refcount.
            entry.get_mut().num_incoming -= 1;

            // If the refcount hits zero, add all adjacent nodes to the queue
            // and remove the node.
            if entry.get().num_incoming == 0 {
                let node = entry.remove();
                queue.extend(node.outgoing);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Better examples of ID-based graphs can be found in the [petgraph](https://docs.rs/petgraph) crate, which is quite widely used.